# What happens when you play Cloudshift on Borderland Ranger?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I believe that when I play [Cloudshift](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cloudshift) which reads:

*Exile target creature you control, then return that card to the battlefield under your control.*

On [Borderland Ranger](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Borderland%20Ranger) which reads:

*When Borderland Ranger enters the battlefield, you may search your library for a basic land card, reveal it, and put it into your hand. If you do, shuffle your library.*

Then Borderland Ranger's triggered ability triggers. Is this correct?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, that's correct. Re-triggering "enters the battlefield" effects is certainly a good use of "flicker" cards like Cloudshift. Perhaps you'd be interested in this [discussion of various uses of Cloudshift](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/32379/whats-the-use-of-blinking-a-creature-out-such-as-with-essence-flux/) for more examples.