# What's the use of blinking a creature out (such as with Essence Flux)?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Essence Flux](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEssence%20Flux%5d) says:

> Exile target creature you control, then return that card to the battlefield under its owner's control. If it's a Spirit, put a +1/+1 counter on it.

So, say I have a 1/1 Sanctuary Cat cast onto the battlefield. According to above, I would exile it, then return it right back? Is that right? I don't see what purpose this serves unless it was a spirit. Could you clarify if I have this right and what the benefit is?

[image: Essence Flux]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**There are many uses for so-called "flicker" effects like from Essence Flux.**

The namesake [Flicker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flicker) was the first card to exile and immediately return the target. This is where the mechanic got its unofficial name.

The creature that returns is a whole new object without any relation to its previous existence. That means that, for example:

- The creature will trigger all applicable "enters the battlefield" and "leaves the battlefield" abilities.
- If the creature you blink is being targeted by a spell or ability, then it will lose track of the creature and not affect it, or will [fizzle](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Fizzle) if that creature was the only target.
- Auras and equipments attached to the creature will fall off of it, and counters get removed.
- It will return untapped.
- All temporary effects, such as from [Giant Growth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Giant%20Growth) or [Death Wind](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Death%20Wind), will be removed.
- The new creature has no damage marked on it, so it's like an improved regeneration effect.
- If you blink the creature during combat, it will be removed from combat and will neither deal nor take any damage, but (if it was already assigned as a blocker), the creature blocked by it will still be blocked.

Other blink cards such as [Flicker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flicker) can also target enemy creatures (though not at instant speed), which can be a very valuable play at the right time.

In short, blink effects are a powerful trick that can throw a wrench in your opponent's plans at a crucial moment. The +1/+1 counter for spirits is more of a bonus in most cases, but of course it allows you to get even more utility out of this spell.

Comment: I edited Wild Growth to Giant Growth; I assume that's what you meant.

Comment: In general blinking can be done to an enemy creature, but not with this card as it says "target creature you control".

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Correct, thanks. Interestingly enough, when I looked it up, most blink effects can only target permanents you control, and those that can target any are either sorcery speed or tied to a permanent, so there are apparently no real instants to blink permanents controlled by others.

Comment: @Hackworth; which makes sense to me; the ability to stop your opponent's creatures from attacking, or remove all Auras on them, would probably be quite powerful.

Comment: I get this is an old post and this doesn't apply to Essence Flux, but my favorite use for flicker effects isn't on the list - it allows you take back control of stolen creatures.  Flicker effects are almost universally worded "...return it to the battlefield under its owner's control".  I've used a Flickerform on a creature with abilities that cause opponents to gain control of it to excellent effect.

Comment: @gatherer818 and it can do the reverse too - certain flicker effects, most notably [Cloudshift](https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=489581) don't return the creature to the owner, but say they are put back in under your control, removing the until end of turn from a stolen creature (via [Act of Treason](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=489479) type spells)